# Is it possible to quote string with user input? c#

Tags: c#, string, quotes

May I know if it's possible for me to do something like this?

```
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
string strNewValue = "{ \"name\" : '" + userInput + "'}";
```

if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted this?

```
string strNewValue = "{ \"name\" : \"" + userInput + "\"}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will certainly work. 
seems like you are trying to convert the user input into a json object. you don't need to hardcode the string as like json object. use JsonSerializer instead. Have a look at it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197957(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: Or better yet, Json.NET, which is the unofficial standard (even ASP.NET uses it now): http://james.newtonking.com/json.